Real-time Appwrite data querying (Riverpod: future + stream)
I'm doing a YouTube tutorial and I'm stuck on a particular point. I may be wrong, but I feel that there is a better solution than the one in the video.
So from appwrite the data retrieval is done in two "steps". The first would be to retrieve the current state with a FutureProvider (getTweetsProvider), and then "monitor" the changes with a StreamProvider (getLatestTweetProvider). At least that is what the video's author recommends.
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  return ref.watch(getTweetsProvider).when(
        data: (tweets) {
          return ref.watch(getLatestTweetProvider).when(
                data: (tweet) {
                  if (tweet.events.contains(
                      'databases.*.collections.${AppwriteConstants.tweetsCollection}.documents.*.create')) {
                    tweets.insert(0, TweetModel.fromMap(tweet.payload));
                  }
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: tweets.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final tweet = tweets.elementAt(index);
                      return TweetCard(tweet: tweet);
                    },
                  );
                },
                error: (error, stackTrace) =>
                    ErrorText(errorTxt: error.toString()),
                // I don't really like it ...
                loading: () => ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: tweets.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final tweet = tweets.elementAt(index);
                    return TweetCard(tweet: tweet);
                  },
                ),
              );
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(errorTxt: error.toString()),
        loading: () => const Loader(),
      );
}

The problem I have is that I don't really like the fact that I have to put the data from the FutureProvider in the loading part of the StreamProvider.
I thought of making the original ConsumerWidget into a ConsumerStatefulWidget and calling FutureProvider in the initState. However, no matter how I try this, it fails. The goal is to retrieve the data into a variable (List tweets) when the application starts, and then just listen to the StreamProvider in the build.
Can this be done?
I was able to do it without provider in a small simple application, but the Riverpod solution caught me.
List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];
RealtimeSubscription? subscription;
late final Client client;
final databaseID = '...';
final itemsCollection = '...';
late final Databases database;

void loadItems() async {
  try {
    final res = await database.listDocuments(
        collectionId: itemsCollection, databaseId: databaseID);
    setState(() {
      items = List<Document>.from(res.documents).map((e) => e.data).toList();
    });
  } on AppwriteException catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.message);
  }
}

void subscribe() {
  final realtime = Realtime(client);

  subscription = realtime.subscribe(
      ['databases.$databaseID.collections.$itemsCollection.documents']);

  subscription!.stream.listen((data) {
    if (data.payload.isNotEmpty) {
      if (data.events
          .contains('databases.*.collections.*.documents.*.create')) {
        var item = data.payload;
        items.add(item);
        setState(() {});
      } else if (data.events
          .contains('databases.*.collections.*.documents.*.delete')) {
        var item = data.payload;
        items.removeWhere((it) => it['\$id'] == item['\$id']);
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  client = Client();

  client
      .setEndpoint('...')
      .setProject('...')
      .setSelfSigned(status: true);
  database = Databases(client);
  loadItems();
  subscribe();
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  subscription?.close();
  super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Appwrite Realtime Demo'),
    ),
    body: ListView(children: [
      ...items.map((item) => ListTile(
            title: Text(item['name']),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () => _removeItem(item['\$id']),
            ),
          )),
    ]),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () {
        // dialog to add new item
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Add new item'),
            content: TextField(
              controller: _nameController,
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('Add'),
                onPressed: () {
                  // add new item
                  final name = _nameController.text;
                  if (name.isNotEmpty) {
                    _nameController.clear();
                    _addItem(name);
                  }
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}

U P D A T E
O.K. I think I found the solution.
Instead of the second when, use whenData. It makes the code more consistent and clearer.
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  return ref.watch(getTweetsProvider).when(
        data: (tweets) {
          ref.watch(getLatestTweetProvider).whenData((tweet) {
            if (tweet.events.contains(
                'databases.*.collections.${AppwriteConstants.tweetsCollection}.documents.*.create')) {
              tweets.insert(0, TweetModel.fromMap(tweet.payload));
            }
          });
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: tweets.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final tweet = tweets.elementAt(index);
              return TweetCard(tweet: tweet);
            },
          );
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(errorTxt: error.toString()),
        loading: () => const Loader(),
      );
}

